# Let $X$ be a metric space. If $A ⊂ X$ is a compact set, prove that for any open covering, there exists a countable subcovering.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space. If $A ⊂ X$ has the property that every infinite subset of
A has an accumulation point in $A$, show that for any open covering of $A$, there exists a countable subcovering.

I know that $A$ can be proved to be a compact set. Then I am thinking of creating a countable base of $A$ with finite open balls of radius $1/n$ covering $A$.
My question is how do I select a countable subcovering of constructed open covering of $A$.

Comment: If your $A$ is a compact subset of $X$, don't you already know for every open cover, you have a finite subcover, and surely then it is countable.

Comment: By countable I mean countably infinite

Comment: If you insist on countably infinite, then you have a problem when you start with a finite cover. If you restrict to infinite covers, just take a finite subcover, and add countably many open sets from the original cover.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Suppose there is family of open sets $O_1,\ldots,O_n,\ldots$ such that $A \subset \cup O_n$ but there is no countable subcovering. Construct the sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \in A \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i $ and look for its accumulation points

Comment: But $A$ is a compact set so it will have a finite subcovering. Can you please prove the statement instead?

Comment: Do you want to prove that $A$ is compact? The finite subcovering is just the definition of compactness. (The hint I gave works in any topological space!)

Comment: No, it is already given that $A$ is compact. I want to prove that under such condition, for any open covering, there exists a countable subcovering.

Comment: Whats your definition of compact?

Comment: If $A$ is compact, then any open covering of $A$ has a finite subcovering

Comment: If it has a finite subcovering it has a countable subcovering by definition and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: by countable I meant countably infinite

Comment: It's impossible to prove, because it`s false.Think about $[0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$. $\mathcal{F} = { (-1,0.5) , (0, 1.5)}$ is an open covering that has no "countably infinite" sub-covering (because it has NO "countably infinite" subset, as it is finite)